# Checking if dictionary is empty using conditional statement in python is throwing a key error

Tags: python

I am sort of new to Python so I was reading through Pro Python and it had this section about passing variable keyword arguments to function. After reading that section I wrote the following code which doesn't seem to work.

```
def fun(**a):
    return a['height'] if a is not {} else 0
```

I got a key error when I called fun with no arguments. How should I change the code so that it returns a['height'] if a is not a null dictionary and returns 0 if it is a null dictionary?

Comment: I love it!  Three identical answers within one minute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing if `a` *the same object* as a random empty dictionary, not if that dictionary has the key `height`. `is not` and `is` test for *identity*, not equality.

You can create any number of empty dictionaries, but they would not be the *same object*:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {}
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

If you want to return a default value if a key is missing, use the [`dict.get()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) here:

```
return a.get('height', 0)
```

or use `not a` to test for an empty dictionary:

```
return a['height'] if a else 0
```

but note you'll still get a `KeyError` if the dictionary has keys other than `'height'`. All empty containers test as *false* in a boolean context, see [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Answer (score 0):

To check if a dictionary has a specific key, do this:

```
if 'height' not in a: return 0
```

Or you can use `get()` with a default:

```
return a.get('height', 0)
```

Comment: Yours takes a different approach than the rest.. But you seem to have not finished the code sir.

Comment: Typo.  Fixed.  Thanks.